# Initialize map of map in java

Tags: java, collections, nested

If I have a Map of Map in Java and I initialized the outer map, then what will be the value of the inner map (null or new Map()) ?

For example, I have:

```
Map<User, Map<Component, Float>> summaryByEmp = new TreeMap<>();
```

Now, what will be the value of the inner map? Do I need to initialize too?

Comment: There would be no value of the "inner" map, until you specifically add one using `summaryByEmp.put(aUser, aMap)`, where `aMap` could be any `Map<Component, Float>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong with your understanding of `Map` here. Doing

`Map<User, Map<Component, Float>> outerMap = new TreeMap<User, Map<Component, Float>>()`

initializes a `TreeMap` referenced by `outerMap`. The type parameter only says that, the key to be put needs to be of type `User` and the value to the key to be of type `Map<Component, Float>`. Nothing more.

So when you insert a key-value pair of type mentioned, you insert it to the `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 3):

Your map summaryByEmp   will be empty utill you add some key value pair in your map. So question

> what will be the value of inner map

does not arises at very first place

```
Map<User, Map<Component, Float>> summaryByEmp = new TreeMap<>();
```

If you want to add it

```
Map<Component, Float> innerMap = new TreeMap();
summaryByEmp.put(new User(),innerMap  )
```

Answer (score 1):

It will have no value, just like the type `User`, `Component` and `Float`. You will need to add data to the map like:

```
Map<Component, Float> mapVal = new TreeMap<>();
/// Fill mapVal
User u = new User();
summaryByEmp.put(u, mapVal);
```